# Using node js and apache2 web server for (POST, GET..ETC) resources

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, vue.js, apache2

Hello everyone (General Question)!! 
I am trying ot create restFul Api resources (Get, Post, Put etc..) using node js in my vue/angular projects, however my server uses apache web server. Do I need to install Node js in my server? or can i just use it as a dependency in my website project. how can i use node js with apache web server without installing node js in the server.

Thanks! Tonathiu.

Comment: If you are worried about being able to run your Node.js code on your server: Why did you write the code in Node.js in the first place?!

Comment: thanks for the clarification, The things is that currently we use a differnt technology to create web resources(pascal and lazarus)using apache, but i  am trying to see how we can transition to node js, since we already use it when we build for production and we use npm for package management ( in this case nose js isn't install in the server)I was just thinking i can just connect to the database and from there create resources.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to install Node js in my server?

If you want to use Node.js on your server, then you will need to install it.

> or can i just use it as a dependency in my website project.

The state of "being a dependency" means "it must be installed on the server".

> how can i use node js with apache web server without installing node js in the server.

Install it on some other server, then communicate with it over the network.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, The things is that currently we use a differnt technology to create web resources(pascal and lazarus)using apache, but i  am trying to see how we can transition to node js, since we already use it when we build for production and we use npm for package management ( in this case nose js isnt intall in the server). Thanks